# Macro function identifier not found

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I created an assert marco that works fine but wanted to make one to break. I copied the assert one and renamed it but not it doesn't work when i use it in one header file but it works everywhere else.

I'm getting this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'RADIANT_TEST_BREAK': identifier not found  Sandbox F:\Path\Buffer.h    63
```

Both macros are in the same file, Core.h which is included wherever i need it.

```
#define RADIANT_CORE_ASSERT(x, ...) { if(!(x)) { RADIANT_CORE_ERROR("Assertion Failed: {0}", __VA_ARGS__); __debugbreak(); } }

#define RADIANT_TEST_BREAK(x, ...) { if(!(x)) { RADIANT_CORE_ERROR("Assertion Failed: {0}", __VA_ARGS__); __debugbreak(); } }
```

I have no idea why the break one doesn't work in that one place

here is the method i am running it from

```
struct BufferElement
    {
        std::string Name;
        ShaderDataType Type;
        uint32_t Size;
        uint32_t Offset;
        bool Normalized;

        BufferElement(ShaderDataType type, const std::string& name, bool normalized = false)
            : Name(name), Type(type), Size(ShaderDataTypeSize(type)), Offset(0), Normalized(normalized)
        {
        }

        uint32_t GetComponentCount() const
        {
            switch (Type)
            {
            case ShaderDataType::Float:   return 1;
            case ShaderDataType::Float2:  return 2;
            }

            RADIANT_TEST_BREAK(false, "Unknown ShaderDataType!");
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

If i swap RADIANT_TEST_BREAK for RADIANT_CORE_ASSERT It works.

Comment: `RADIANT_CORE_ERROR` was what again?

Comment: i forgot the error code, sorry. i'll add it now

and RADIANT_CORE_ERROR just called spd log.
This is the macro i used for it:

#define RADIANT_CORE_ERROR(...)   ::Radiance::Log::GetCoreLogger()->error(__VA_ARGS__)

Comment: @RadiantMin3 Thanks for the update. It seems your compiler doesn't recognize the macro at all (it wasn't replaced by the preprocessor), but I see no obvious reason for this. But sometimes compilers have hickups, so maybe build from scratch and check for typos and that you included the correct files.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I found what was causing the problem.

i had the definition in an ifdef but not in the else

```
#ifdef RADIANT_ENABLE_ASSERTS

#define RADIANT_CORE_ASSERT(x, ...) { if(!(x)) { RADIANT_CORE_ERROR("Assertion Failed: {0}", __VA_ARGS__); __debugbreak(); } }

#define RADIANT_TEST_BREAK(x, ...) { if(!(x)) { RADIANT_CORE_ERROR("Assertion Failed: {0}", __VA_ARGS__); __debugbreak(); } }

#else
#define RADIANT_CORE_ASSERT(x, ...)

//Make sure to include this line
#define RADIANT_TEST_BREAK(x, ...)
#endif
```

This seems to only be a problem in one place which i still don't know why but this fixed it for me.